# How to choose a sub-class in Java

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

i am making a program which has a super class called `Building`, this class has one variable which is the address of the building. Then i have two sub-classes one is called `Apartment` the other one is called `Restaurant`.
I defined those classes like this:

```
public class Apartment extends Building;
public class Restaurant extends Building;
```

Now i have a function `public void register(Building build);`
and i want to know how can i choose a sub-class to store the information by receiving the super class only.
E.g:

```
0.Apartment
1.Restaurant
Which building do you have?
```

Now depending on user's answer i will ask

```
How many rooms, bathrooms, etc.
```

My starter point is `Building` class now i need to choose, if the user answered `0` i will be using `Apartment` sub-class, otherwise i will use `Restaurant` sub-class.
How can i do this?
Let me know if there is a better way to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: Some kind of [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) maybe

Comment: You should really add some more code to the question. Are you looking for a "pattern" name commonly used to solve a problem like this? Are you simply using how to write a switch or if statement to interpret user input? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with method overloading:
Make register methods with your sub-classes as arguments. Do the sub-class 
specific work in those methods and then 
call a 
private register(Building building)
 method to do the common work.